# Average value of a Vector

Tags: integration, vector-spaces

How to find the average temperature on part of the plane $3 x + 4 y + z = 6$ over the square $|x|\leq 1$, $|y|\leq 1$ where the temperature is $f(x,y,z) = e^{-z}$.

Please give some hint

Comment: Average value of a function $f$ over a region $R$ is the integral $\iint_R f dA$ divided by the area of $R$. So just integrate $e^{3x+4y-6}$ over the square, and then divide the answer by the area of that piece of the plane.

Comment: Thanks a million. This will help!